# iPhone app "has active assertions beyond permitted time"

Tags: iphone, crash-reports

I'm trying to make sense of some crash logs I received for my iPhone app. The main thing that I can see that's useful is:

```
Application Specific Information:
MyMoodTrack[144] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x73c6480> identifier: Suspending process: MyMoodTrack[144] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:26 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}
```

This reads to me as if the process has been killed because it was taking too long to start up. Does this sound right? It only happens when the user does not have an internet connection, though I haven't been able to repeat this at my end. Full crash log attached below, though I had trouble getting it to symbolicate properly.

```
Incident Identifier: 368C9C91-43FF-4FB5-AD50-B75D944AFB1B
CrashReporter Key:   18c5260f4e6af9802ba3eb0d838ed5b6dc7b932a
Hardware Model:      iPod3,1
Process:         MyMoodTrack [144]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E39675AA-1E1C-4D39-98DB-A81A1F944DE6/MyMoodTrack.app/MyMoodTrack
Identifier:      MyMoodTrack
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-09-05 22:53:42.306 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.2 (8A400)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
MyMoodTrack[144] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x73c6480> identifier: Suspending process: MyMoodTrack[144] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:26 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4a658 0x31f49000 + 5720
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4c724 0x31f49000 + 14116
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31a762c8 0x31a04000 + 467656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31a78582 0x31a04000 + 476546
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31a218e4 0x31a04000 + 121060
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31a217ec 0x31a04000 + 120812
6   Foundation                      0x32887d60 0x32883000 + 19808
7   MyMoodTrack                     0x000235b8 0x1000 + 140728
8   MyMoodTrack                     0x00022982 0x1000 + 137602
9   MyMoodTrack                     0x0001fdb0 0x1000 + 126384
10  MyMoodTrack                     0x0002125c 0x1000 + 131676
11  MyMoodTrack                     0x000212ac 0x1000 + 131756
12  MyMoodTrack                     0x0001f732 0x1000 + 124722
13  Foundation                      0x3289bfb0 0x32883000 + 102320
14  CoreFoundation                  0x31a6de6c 0x31a04000 + 433772
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31a1e374 0x31a04000 + 107380
16  Foundation                      0x328870bc 0x32883000 + 16572
17  Foundation                      0x3288f452 0x32883000 + 50258
18  UIKit                           0x32f7b444 0x32ea9000 + 861252
19  UIKit                           0x32ffa75e 0x32ea9000 + 1382238
20  UIKit                           0x32f06456 0x32ea9000 + 382038
21  UIKit                           0x32f05a56 0x32ea9000 + 379478
22  UIKit                           0x32f05500 0x32ea9000 + 378112
23  GraphicsServices                0x30672140 0x3066e000 + 16704
24  CoreFoundation                  0x31a75aa4 0x31a04000 + 465572
25  CoreFoundation                  0x31a77848 0x31a04000 + 473160
26  CoreFoundation                  0x31a78626 0x31a04000 + 476710
27  CoreFoundation                  0x31a218e4 0x31a04000 + 121060
28  CoreFoundation                  0x31a217ec 0x31a04000 + 120812
29  GraphicsServices                0x306716e8 0x3066e000 + 14056
30  GraphicsServices                0x30671794 0x3066e000 + 14228
31  UIKit                           0x32eaf2a0 0x32ea9000 + 25248
32  UIKit                           0x32eade10 0x32ea9000 + 19984
33  MyMoodTrack                     0x00002548 0x1000 + 5448
34  MyMoodTrack                     0x000024e4 0x1000 + 5348

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f76c4c 0x31f49000 + 187468
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3201fe44 0x31f49000 + 880196
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3201f894 0x31f49000 + 878740
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3201fa34 0x31f49000 + 879156
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fc3d82 0x31f49000 + 503170
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fbcfcc 0x31f49000 + 475084

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4a658 0x31f49000 + 5720
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4c724 0x31f49000 + 14116
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31a762c8 0x31a04000 + 467656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31a78582 0x31a04000 + 476546
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31a218e4 0x31a04000 + 121060
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31a217ec 0x31a04000 + 120812
6   WebCore                         0x31488056 0x31485000 + 12374
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fc3986 0x31f49000 + 502150
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fb90e4 0x31f49000 + 458980

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4a658 0x31f49000 + 5720
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f4c724 0x31f49000 + 14116
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31a762c8 0x31a04000 + 467656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31a78582 0x31a04000 + 476546
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31a218e4 0x31a04000 + 121060
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31a217ec 0x31a04000 + 120812
6   Foundation                      0x328be71e 0x32883000 + 243486
7   Foundation                      0x3288ec96 0x32883000 + 48278
8   Foundation                      0x329139da 0x32883000 + 592346
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fc3986 0x31f49000 + 502150
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fb90e4 0x31f49000 + 458980

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f6ea20 0x31f49000 + 154144
1   CoreFoundation                  0x31a7be70 0x31a04000 + 491120
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fc3986 0x31f49000 + 502150
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fb90e4 0x31f49000 + 458980

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f76c4c 0x31f49000 + 187468
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31ffebde 0x31f49000 + 744414
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fff1e4 0x31f49000 + 745956
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31ffff7c 0x31f49000 + 749436
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32000096 0x31f49000 + 749718
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f7578a 0x31f49000 + 182154
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f753d6 0x31f49000 + 181206
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31f752ce 0x31f49000 + 180942
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fc3986 0x31f49000 + 502150
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31fb90e4 0x31f49000 + 458980

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x41fff +MyMoodTrack armv7  <65d29eb4377c48dd3e0426e2fae41c24> /var/mobile/Applications/E39675AA-1E1C-4D39-98DB-A81A1F944DE6/MyMoodTrack.app/MyMoodTrack
   0xf3000 -    0xf4fff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <193570c1391880df7da870149117e49e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x300ac000 - 0x300adfff  DataMigration armv7  <2a90bcfdd519f8d7d3487151c77443ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x300ae000 - 0x300bbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <e397de408a0a789f816bc1803ae58faf> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x300ee000 - 0x300f0fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c668de69901cce316252204135b4ce7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x300f1000 - 0x30133fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bc8796c8e011fea9923170d3c948a694> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x30134000 - 0x30134fff  Accelerate armv7  <f4c04cdfdb64d209828315cdd5b60bf9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3022f000 - 0x30279fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <baab09769f92decea73680bc15aa8618> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x304ee000 - 0x3052cfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <cc8d6be7a5021266e26ebd05e9579852> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30622000 - 0x30650fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <2b44ac2fc47fc45c4006d08019688dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3065b000 - 0x30663fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b8fc1381e87a55740d9ac66195039a63> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3066e000 - 0x30679fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7194df9e594ae0fd9d9c600ccf456a08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x306ed000 - 0x3078bfff  Celestial armv7  <7a01b8d8cd2054d9b0d987bda6c52d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3078c000 - 0x30794fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <4ec35c4d1e1e73416aea84537829ce91> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x307ea000 - 0x30824fff  IMAVCore armv7  <2bd608c3f68c2e9cd73212007eaf248d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x3082a000 - 0x3086afff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <94f3f69708e8f008b3f092430f46e4b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3086b000 - 0x308a5fff  CoreMedia armv7  <6df383495d1acd2b036ad674a29d75c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30906000 - 0x309aefff  QuartzCore armv7  <109b4f6a3d2ee5aa1bb5775ab5a489bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30d13000 - 0x30d66fff  EventKit armv7  <7f18bef514a44edeccc9619b10f4f1c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x30d73000 - 0x30fb1fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <83f1b1c1956ed14bf6f6c7923ee9f2fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x311d9000 - 0x31219fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1723726845b73efbeca75b33d75f335a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3124c000 - 0x31285fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d38c937ae3548777da263d2657536189> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31286000 - 0x312b4fff  MIME armv7  <a6dbab95d27cf0fe94c2251df2549e10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x312b5000 - 0x312cafff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x312cb000 - 0x312dbfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e63c6e2198f5542561ba108f4458c17d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31314000 - 0x3139bfff  Message armv7  <32383927596c6b8c0837a5cd4b2bc0d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3139c000 - 0x3139dfff  CoreSurface armv7  <042e433142b7faa4c96b23e555faaf13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x313b2000 - 0x31474fff  CFNetwork armv7  <9fdd61632fd1b48d65daba561528946f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31485000 - 0x319d6fff  WebCore armv7  <859bdd351085819fb4da07d12b41543f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x319e0000 - 0x319e3fff  CertUI armv7  <fff763f01a1037dcd9ce6914e25068ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31a04000 - 0x31ad6fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <17c9c36ae8824496b507446869cd4d9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31b05000 - 0x31b34fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <4c4faee61a6e7d80d6d3a58194075642> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x31bf4000 - 0x31c02fff  Notes armv7  <56a4dfe587cf5b965edbd6c390ccbf24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31c64000 - 0x31c67fff  IOSurface armv7  <e67242f81fd1c0fa5e84b3fae5d310ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31d10000 - 0x31d43fff  iCalendar armv7  <a8def1c4ef73199eee71bc525005831b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31d48000 - 0x31d54fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <7624f0a9e197261f2df43edb86ba0256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31d6c000 - 0x31d72fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <df3c6cea5e6848109a6e033e1d883320> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31e27000 - 0x31f45fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <4022bbf12f11dd1f6b75662c764e7f7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31f49000 - 0x32056fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <3fcf32f3ad8ef745480b5b36efc41953> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32057000 - 0x32086fff  QuickLook armv7  <78442b5e66e7845f89afcc02b6982ef2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x32089000 - 0x3208efff  BluetoothManager armv7  <c3a48ff43d836b3025597f4ff5e5c858> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x320a0000 - 0x320a3fff  ActorKit armv7  <9858fda6756fb624164b7b83aefa6701> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x320a4000 - 0x320a7fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <12f82e44ff36b29f8d0661878be83554> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x320c0000 - 0x320eefff  AppSupport armv7  <2a64271b39599b2180d0dfd3141027ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x320ef000 - 0x32130fff  MessageUI armv7  <01029a352fe073ddf5103bad8274f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x321a4000 - 0x32207fff  AVFoundation armv7  <39ad1d85ae4627ed77de7751e8a3b4ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x32208000 - 0x3220dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <d33678689445fcf1898314262fd1ebd3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3220e000 - 0x32217fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <3b3f590d3bd1fdf29a14769cbe8dc933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x32234000 - 0x32243fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <575a1afc08ed55608075204df14cc5f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32244000 - 0x322e3fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <894df23ebbc4df713d9519141a61dd19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32346000 - 0x32346fff  vecLib armv7  <85f89752df7814c1b243c26f59388523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3234a000 - 0x32374fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <25fba468c726d1a59aa109a5a76631f5> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32375000 - 0x32497fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <dea2c74c8c31430c58301edbe2b6eeb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32498000 - 0x32527fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <7748fd02215f7d77eae9191cba201b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32582000 - 0x325b3fff  CoreLocation armv7  <722c5983f0589013d0243e2512d0dd1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x325b4000 - 0x325c4fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <dd37e6ff7158a0d44c99efa6ad659dd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x325c5000 - 0x32604fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b96f5e231a3e39677b5e3621d61d2f11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32605000 - 0x32692fff  ImageIO armv7  <abf07fc0430aaf2a2823753c78061aac> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32695000 - 0x326abfff  RawCamera armv7  <78168f60a21e67ce307c5ce30054dba6> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x326b2000 - 0x326e1fff  CoreText armv7  <76eb1b63d684c3d21dba9e8129666d2f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3277a000 - 0x3285bfff  GameKitServices armv7  <5bfca52ad46cbf5f8ea3888f646f3511> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x3285c000 - 0x32865fff  AccountSettings armv7  <cd5665c4a135694944eca0870d5350c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32883000 - 0x329a2fff  Foundation armv7  <c985a61696030b4d1bdc8fe010f4e43b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32a98000 - 0x32aa1fff  CoreVideo armv7  <58180e899ec56cd8bca00221dea2bc32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32aad000 - 0x32ac5fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <436e3b257ba088ca6f773961ce619892> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32ac6000 - 0x32d60fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <fbc3f7ad1260a159d75be53218fa9e0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32d61000 - 0x32d8afff  ContentIndex armv7  <40405e868ddfb485115719c167925b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x32d8d000 - 0x32d90fff  ApplePushService armv7  <0477bf826cbba75183069e1e80879a99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x32ea9000 - 0x34053fff  UIKit armv7  <6c767127e477e6ac7b7f083857ca8064> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34063000 - 0x34065fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1fdf9182a63464743901526caf39240a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x34069000 - 0x3416cfff  CoreData armv7  <0abaeddf54d093fa5cf680b0d644d8e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34266000 - 0x34285fff  Conference armv7  <f38c0563d62880f21ee676529aeafa47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Conference.framework/Conference
0x34286000 - 0x34326fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <89553a61e05078fd178ac0ea2081ae40> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34327000 - 0x34355fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <475259824770c6ff1b63f30238b3ea81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3436c000 - 0x34377fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34392000 - 0x34394fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <06dd6032c40b1feb094d63eeb2002d6d> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34399000 - 0x3439afff  Marco armv7  <89d4f32ac1cbb0b4f5066308fa5f422a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3439b000 - 0x343bafff  Bom armv7  <c73b68b11b2801cefbfbdb6328a7fcfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343d0000 - 0x34476fff  WebKit armv7  <a1d04572b3214188f60f2d1961ac1fe8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3447b000 - 0x3448cfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <5e827d18f317b5ce7c61c91656ebc88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x344cd000 - 0x344d1fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <942a91e5920a8798c1a1cf75f0750b2f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34500000 - 0x34508fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <0bd0c65f4350b5d81f81449fae029a04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3452f000 - 0x34565fff  Security armv7  <7cea1027f1a381b8d6c5ffae4dae0d22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34590000 - 0x345bafff  DataAccess armv7  <190e9fd23dcbf029e5a8cdb9fb56befc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x345ec000 - 0x34626fff  IOKit armv7  <5e0169de165c2fd25a2ddac1f3e19d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34629000 - 0x34636fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <27ad6b3a74ce1068586eabd6a553183f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34637000 - 0x3463efff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5d079712f5a39708647292bccbd4c4e0> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34642000 - 0x3472afff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <9bcf5fe3e7abc344425e581ff2896579> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3472b000 - 0x3474afff  MobileSync armv7  <be1b235840ae625d49f684c39ab083da> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3474b000 - 0x34794fff  GMM armv7  <9c4efdff49ea9e6a17b5d44bcd98b6c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x347c2000 - 0x348e6fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <802e4d5c449b69d9552809e5230baa84> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x348e9000 - 0x3492efff  IMCore armv7  <d5045ad82f9b89b1d4992f1f500724fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x34979000 - 0x349bdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <36b9bc7d02e29c8d321dd0d7bf7e115e> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x349e2000 - 0x349e9fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <6d417a70ec3abd8258ed0fbab0994518> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x349ea000 - 0x349edfff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <85f01f53a7455a34fbdedc76bd692d74> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x349ee000 - 0x34a01fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <9fbf2930731e2da9863eacdff8b121a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34c78000 - 0x34c7afff  MobileInstallation armv7  <74e2bd725da63513053b4fa41d8cd89c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34d1f000 - 0x34d67fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b4a2849c10d100a178a3c2d9f6af523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34d68000 - 0x34d9afff  AddressBook armv7  <3dde743216bbf016019b59f821dda6e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34d9b000 - 0x34eb4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <c4f4fd74dfa672fb4d84914585bbada5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34f5a000 - 0x34f70fff  EAP8021X armv7  <4177ec92cd0e2a4a23c79fac68de5c2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34f71000 - 0x34f7afff  ITSync armv7  <e00a78c04f8ae7515da25fdc09281f4f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x34f7b000 - 0x34fe9fff  ProofReader armv7  <479bd40ac65cb7e6c3000d79d649571f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x350c7000 - 0x350f0fff  IMFoundation armv7  <8e003a136638c28edc7b5333b8166b5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3524a000 - 0x352f3fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

Comment: I have the same trouble. Can anyone help me ?
[my question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450342/app-has-active-assertions-beyond-permitted-time

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you trying to do synchronous networking in the main UI thread?  That won't work.

Did you test your app on a device with no internet connection?  (Airplane mode ON.  Or wifi ON and network cable unplugged from the back of your wifi access point).  If not, do so.

Comment: This was the problem, and I identified soon after by doing pretty much as suggested (though turning airplane mode on was enough).

Comment: @alku83  I am also facing a similar crash.I call a service on main thread while launching my application.Can you plz help me in fixing this.Can you plz tell how you have fixed the similar crash in your application? I believe your pointers would help me...

Comment: @Dinakar You need to ensure that you are doing your network calls from a background thread, not on the main thread.

Comment: 1. I understand 'synchronous networking in the main UI thread' is wrong. OK. Understood. How is that related to the wifi issue? Say we don't have internet...we make a request, it times out and we handle its error. Isn't that it? 2. How did you figure out the error was because of synchronous networking? Did you say that because of seeing `preventThrottleDownUI`?

Comment: The OS can kill your app before a network request times out or the error is handled, if that takes "too long" and blocks the main UI thread.

Comment: too long you mean like more than 60 seconds? Perhaps 5 minutes? FYI we do have a **non-blocking** network request in our app that goes on for 5 minutes or more and doesn't crash...

Comment: How long is up to Apple/iOS.  But non-blocking should be OK.  Test in Airplane mode, or with a bad connection.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are executing a task in background for more than the permitted time.
You can avoid this crash by ending the bgtask properly.
[IOs7 app crashing when in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839269/ios7-app-crashing-when-in-background)

```
<SBProcessAssertion: 0x73c6480> identifier: Suspending process: MyMoodTrack[144] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:26 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI
```

In your crash log, it says MyMoodTrack process was suspended. My thought on this is the process's permitted background time has exceeded it's limit.