# Application Crash because of active assertions beyond permitted time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, core-location

The crash report details:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
MyApp[123] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x4b52f0> identifier: CoreLocationBackgroundClient process: MyApp[579] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:123 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.980 (user 13.980, system 0.000), 1% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.251, 0% CPU
```

and thread 3 is:

```
Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30e67004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30e671fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x381ea3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x381e9124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3816c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3816c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x373a7bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x373a7a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3743b58a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x333c972e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x333c95e8 thread_start + 0
```

The application uses GPS. Any idea why this crash is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app "has active assertions beyond permitted time"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654716/iphone-app-has-active-assertions-beyond-permitted-time)

Comment: @rishi. This is the first time I am facing this problem. And you can check my old questions.

Comment: I just gave the link of question which is esactly same as yours, i hope that will help you in fixing the issue. No hard feeling!!!!

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. I can see that the synchronous connection is a problem. My application is works fine when the GPS is ON. But if the GPS is off , then it is getting crashed.

Comment: that simply mean when you are getting data everything is fine, and once data stopped there is an issue, you need to check the handling of data in your code. Not much sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're using the wrong kind of background processing. The 600 seconds is the give-away. That suggests that you're using the task completion API, which gives applications a finite amount of time (currently ten minutes) to finish off certain activities before they are suspended.

If you want to continue to monitor GPS location while in the background you need to use particular Core Location APIs (and set the appropriate flag in your Info.plist).

Comment: Hi, I am already using the Required background modes as Location Services (GPS) for the background processing. Tasks are working great when the app is in Background. And I got this crash suddenly like, I have turned-off my application GPS and tried to do some tasks. I guess there is some problem in NSURLConnection

Comment: Hi, i'm using the NStimer in background and send http request and handle it, but it thought this error can you help to me?

Comment: @JigneshB That sounds like a new question. Location services are a special case on iOS. NSTimer won't work beyond ten minutes so you'll need to do something like background fetch.