# iPhone app using Facebook SDK crashes with "has active assertions beyond permitted time" error

Tags: ios, facebook, crash

I have an iPhone (iOS native) app that uses the current Facebook iOS SDK. When attempting to connect my app via the Single-Sign-On process, I frequently get a crash stating my app "has active assertions beyond permitted time". After reviewing other similar reports here on Stack Overflow (such as [iPhone app "has active assertions beyond permitted time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654716/iphone-app-has-active-assertions-beyond-permitted-time)) I don't find anything that seems to fit my situation. I am following Facebook's recommended practices for integrating SSO (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso). That means I am calling the Facebook SDK on my main thread. Facebook doesn't seem to think this will be a problem.

Can anyone explain what this particular error means? I assume that some iOS supervisor mechanism is killing my app because it's taking too long doing something, but what particular something? Is it because the foreground task is locked for too long? Or what?

Here's an iOS app crash report showing the error.

```
Incident Identifier: F2486727-9EAC-4D7F-8A45-07AC51ADD186
CrashReporter Key:   b3825455d63e6e7f659074b5ea5fb89cf8ed1b9f
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         JouleBug [2060]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/FA3DB4BA-92AF-4D14-AD3A-1553EFA1FA16/JouleBug.app/JouleBug
Identifier:      JouleBug
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-05 14:44:30.751 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
JouleBug[2060] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0xe2ed000> identifier: Suspending process: JouleBug[2060] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:52 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 6.190 (user 6.190, system 0.000), 84% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.515, 21% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e23dcc __open + 8
1   Foundation                        0x31ab412a _NSmkstemp83 + 322
2   Foundation                        0x31ab3f4a _NSCreateTemporaryFile + 118
3   Foundation                        0x31ab3b36 _NSWriteBytesToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 186
4   Foundation                        0x31ab3a70 _NSWriteBytesToFile + 24
5   Foundation                        0x31ab3a48 -[NSData(NSData) writeToFile:atomically:] + 76
6   JouleBug                          0x00109c5c -[LazyJSONModelMapper save] (LazyJSONModelMapper.m:106)
7   JouleBug                          0x00109b40 __36-[LazyJSONModelMapper initWithFile:]_block_invoke_0 (LazyJSONModelMapper.m:63)
8   Foundation                        0x31a856c2 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 286
9   Foundation                        0x31b1152a __67-[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]_block_invoke_0 + 22
10  CoreFoundation                    0x311d6540 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 64
11  CoreFoundation                    0x31162090 _CFXNotificationPost + 1400
12  Foundation                        0x31a853e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
13  UIKit                             0x3090524e -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 786
14  UIKit                             0x30895ef8 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2088
15  UIKit                             0x30895560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
16  UIKit                             0x30894f34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
17  GraphicsServices                  0x331db224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
18  CoreFoundation                    0x311deacc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
19  CoreFoundation                    0x311de32e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
20  CoreFoundation                    0x311dd03e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
21  CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
22  CoreFoundation                    0x31160366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
23  GraphicsServices                  0x331da432 GSEventRunModal + 130
24  UIKit                             0x308c3cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
25  JouleBug                          0x00033ac6 main (main.m:14)
26  JouleBug                          0x00003900 0x1000 + 10496

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e143a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x35a2eea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x35a2ebc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e24cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aaf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aacc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e240d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352a4674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                           0x362614e8 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                           0x362c016c _ZL19SendDelegateMessageP12NSInvocation + 700
4   WebKit                            0x36bfad80 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 112
5   CoreFoundation                    0x3120ca7c ___forwarding___ + 660
6   CoreFoundation                    0x31167648 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
7   WebCore                           0x3631bf7c WebCore::FrameLoader::finishedParsing() + 56
8   WebCore                           0x3631bf12 WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 186
9   WebCore                           0x3631be50 WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::finished() + 16
10  WebCore                           0x3630cfbe WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::prepareToStopParsing() + 106
11  WebCore                           0x3630cc9e WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::finish() + 90
12  WebCore                           0x3630cc3a WebCore::Document::finishParsing() + 14
13  WebCore                           0x36309e62 WebCore::DocumentWriter::endIfNotLoadingMainResource() + 74
14  WebCore                           0x363084fa WebCore::DocumentLoader::finishedLoading() + 74
15  WebCore                           0x363559c8 WebCore::FrameLoader::finishedLoading() + 48
16  WebCore                           0x36355938 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 88
17  WebCore                           0x363558c2 _ZN7WebCoreL16didFinishLoadingEP16_CFURLConnectionPKv + 46
18  CFNetwork                         0x349997ee URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading(URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 186
19  CFNetwork                         0x3498e49e URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 418
20  CFNetwork                         0x3498e592 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 662
21  CFNetwork                         0x3498e19c URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 100
22  CFNetwork                         0x3498e0d2 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 150
23  CoreFoundation                    0x311deacc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
24  CoreFoundation                    0x311de32e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
25  CoreFoundation                    0x311dd03e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
26  CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
27  CoreFoundation                    0x31160366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
28  WebCore                           0x36304c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
29  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
30  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e14004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e141fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                    0x311de3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                    0x311dd124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                    0x311dd444 CFRunLoopRun + 92
6   JouleBug                          0x00071800 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4772)
7   Foundation                        0x31a92a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                        0x31b2658a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e14004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e141fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                    0x311de3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                    0x311dd124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                    0x31160366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                        0x31a92bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                        0x31a92a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                        0x31b2658a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e24570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                    0x311e263a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e14004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e141fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                    0x311de3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                    0x311dd124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                    0x31160366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                        0x31a86b6e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                        0x31aa051c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 72
8   JouleBug                          0x0014e516 0x1000 + 1365270
9   Foundation                        0x31a92a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
10  Foundation                        0x31b2658a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
11  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
12  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e2451c __rename + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e15b6e rename + 2
2   Foundation                        0x31ab3dac _NSWriteBytesToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 816
3   Foundation                        0x31ab3a70 _NSWriteBytesToFile + 24
4   Foundation                        0x31ab3a48 -[NSData(NSData) writeToFile:atomically:] + 76
5   JouleBug                          0x00109c5c -[LazyJSONModelMapper save] (LazyJSONModelMapper.m:106)
6   JouleBug                          0x00109a4e -[LazyJSONModelMapper initWithFile:] (LazyJSONModelMapper.m:85)
7   JouleBug                          0x001097c6 -[LazyJSONModelMapper initWithData:fromFile:] (LazyJSONModelMapper.m:45)
8   JouleBug                          0x00089e5c +[GameDataManager storePinFromPinDict:] (GameDataManager.m:238)
9   JouleBug                          0x000dd378 +[GameDataLoader processData:] (GameDataLoader.m:62)
10  JouleBug                          0x000ae300 +[DataLoader refreshDataSynchronously] (DataLoader.m:54)
11  JouleBug                          0x000ae29c __25+[DataLoader refreshData]_block_invoke_0 (DataLoader.m:36)
12  Foundation                        0x31acbe50 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 196
13  Foundation                        0x31aad38c -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 856
14  JouleBug                          0x000ccb06 -[TimedBlockOperation start] (NSOperationExtensions.m:96)
15  Foundation                        0x31b1678c __block_global_6 + 96
16  libdispatch.dylib                 0x35a22c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
17  libdispatch.dylib                 0x35a2e7b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 256
18  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aadf4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
19  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aacc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e24cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aaf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aacc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e24cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aaf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aacc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e14004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e141fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                    0x311de3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                    0x311dd124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                    0x3116049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                    0x31160366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                           0x3632e0d2 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 122
7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352b05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x37e24cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aaf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x352aacc8 start_wqthread + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: Do you get crash on the simulator as well?

Comment: No, but I can't install the Facebook app in the simulator. When I run it on the simulator, the Facebook SDK uses the browser to present the signin page.

Answer (score 1):

I finally tracked this down. Just as in other similar incidents reported on Stack Overflow, this turned out to be a problem with a scheduled operation attempting to run in the background. My problem is resolved.