# App has active assertions beyond permitted time

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, crash-reports

```
Jul  3 18:20:22  Testautoreleasepool[9079] <Warning>: update2: x:-1.004532 y:0.006363 z:0.093887 1311
Jul  3 18:20:22  Testautoreleasepool[9079] <Warning>: update2: x:-1.004532 y:0.006363 z:0.093887 1312
Jul  3 18:20:22  Testautoreleasepool[9079] <Warning>: update2: x:-1.004532 y:0.006363 z:0.093887 1313
Jul  3 18:20:22  Testautoreleasepool[9079] <Warning>: update2: x:-1.004532 y:0.006363 z:0.093887 1314
Jul  3 18:20:22  Testautoreleasepool[9079] <Warning>: update2: x:-1.004532 y:0.006363 z:0.093887 1315
Jul  3 18:20:22  backboardd[66] <Warning>: Testautorelease[9079] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
    {(
        <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1dd68310> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: Testautorelease[9079] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:9079 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
    )}
Jul  3 18:20:22  backboardd[66] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of Testautorelease[9079]...
Jul  3 18:20:22  ReportCrash[9134] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (793.00)
Jul  3 18:20:23  backboardd[66] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Jul  3 18:20:23  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:net.imore.testAcc[0xeeb9]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul  3 18:20:23  ReportCrash[9134] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Jul  3 18:20:23  backboardd[66] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:net.imore.testAcc[0xeeb9]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

"net.imore.testAcc" is my app bundle ID.
When the App enter to the background after 10 minutes, the App was killed. I have double "endBackgroundTask". I didn't create any NSURLConnections. But the App was killed. (I run this on ipod4,and after 10 minutes the app is killed. I find the log above in Xcode->Organizer-Myipod->Console)

I want to develope a soft that can recieve CMAccelerationData even if the app enter to the background more than 10 minutes.

What can I do? Can anyone help me? thank you...

My project url:  http://qq644531343.opendrive.com/files/Ml8yMjE4MjIzN19heHNtQl82YzYz/Testautoreleasepool2.zip

main code:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //[self redirectNSLogToDocumentFolder];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 80, 40);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(changebg) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.window addSubview:btn];

    //init motionManager
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)changebg
{
    int i = arc4random()%255+1;
    int j = arc4random()%255+1;
    int k = arc4random()%255+1;
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:i/255.0f green:j/255.0f blue:k/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"enter background");
        [self update];
    }
    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier =
    [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {

        NSLog(@"begin in background after 10 minutes");
        [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f;
        [self update2];
        [self endBackgroundTask];

    }];

}

-(void)update
{
    NSLog(@"update");
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData,NSError *error)
     {
         CMAcceleration acceleration=accelerometerData.acceleration;
         NSLog(@"update: x:%f y:%f z:%f timeremian:%f",acceleration.x,acceleration.y,acceleration.z,[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);

     }];

}

-(void)update2
{
        int i=0;
        NSLog(@"begin back acc");
        while (1) {
             @autoreleasepool {
                 //app enter foreground
                 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] > 600.0f) {
                     break;
                 }
                 CMAcceleration acceleration = motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration;
                 NSLog(@"update2: x:%f y:%f z:%f %d",acceleration.x,acceleration.y,acceleration.z,i++);
              }
        }
    NSLog(@"%s stoped acc",__func__);
    [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"enter foreground");
    if (self.backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
        [self endBackgroundTask];
    }
}

- (BOOL) isMultitaskingSupported{

    BOOL result = NO;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]
         respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]){
        result = [[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported];
    }
    return result;

}

- (void) endBackgroundTask{

    NSLog(@"end task");

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    AppDelegate
    *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) {

        AppDelegate
        *strongSelf = weakSelf;

        if (strongSelf != nil){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
            strongSelf.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You want your app to keep running after 10 minutes in the background?

Comment: Yes , I wish the app to keep running after 10 minutes in the background.But it always be killed. Could you help me?

Comment: There is a strange thing. When I press the Run button on Xcode ,it runs ok on ipod and not exit after 10 minutes in the background. But if I makes it to an ipa, and then run on ipod, it will be killed after 10 minutes in the background. I also use the Instruments of the Xcode to oberve the living memory, it's seens normally and keeps at 600kb.So it's not memory leak.